# Couchbase lite rename database

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

How can I rename an existing couchbase lite database (I'd like to avoid creating a new db and having to copy the contents over if possible). Is this the same as replicate to a database locally that has the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Since you map your local database to a remote couchbase bucket using the CBLReplication classes, I can't see any reason why renaming the database shouldn't work.

Just make sure you close your CBLDatabase first:

```
database.close()
```

And use the NSFileManager to move the database `mydb.cblite` from within the `CBLManager.sharedInstance().directory` as you like:

```
let databaseManager = CBLManager.sharedInstance()
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let sourceName = "\(database.name).cblite"
let targetName = "my-new-name.cblite"
if let sourcePath = NSURL(databaseManager.directory,isDirectory:true).URLbyAppendingURLComponent(sourceName).path,
let targetPath = NSURL(databaseManager.directory,isDirectory:true).URLbyAppendingURLComponent(targetName).path{
  fileManager.moveItemAtPath(sourcePath,atPath: targetPath)
}
```

And afterwards reopen the connection to the database with the same `CBLReplication` settings as before:

```
let database = databaseManager.databaseNamed("my-new-name")
```

Please keep in mind you might also move the `mydb attachments` directory first. And after reopening the connection making sure all of your code is using the new reference for querying etc.

PS: The code used here is written from memory, so it may not work copied 1:1 - but you should get the idea.